# ¿Cuándo se usa el motivo de rechazo de edición "Edición que promociona un producto o servicio"?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas, revisiones

Hace poco hice una edición a la pregunta de un OP, la cual fue rechazada y el comentario es:

> Esta edición desmejora la publicación para promocionar un producto o
>   servicio, o es deliberadamente destructiva.

No quiero entrar en discusión si la edición está bien o mal, claramente para mí está bien, por eso la sugerí, lo que quisiera es saber ¿A qué hace referencia este comentario en la edición? ¿De dónde sale esta respuesta? ¿Es automatizado y no hay más opciones para elegir?

La edición es cuestión es esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/158049

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por un lado, el mensaje es una de las opciones a elegir para rechazar una edición. Pero en este caso...consideras una edición que suprime todo un código de ejemplo por esto ` <a href="contacto.html"></a><span class="butn">¡Me interesa!</span>`

 que es _claramente_ correcta?

Comment: Tu edición se ha considerado destructiva. No sé por qué te has cargado el snippet y el CSS, ¿que problema había en ello?

Comment: Gracias por responder Pikoh, en la publicación el OP preguntaba porqué un href no funcionaba (una etiqueta <a>) y mostraba un largo código CSS innecesario al caso, por eso me pareció correcto decir que era información irrelevante

Comment: Entiendo tu punto de vista. Pero eso no debe llevar a una edición "destructiva". Debes añadir un comentario al OP indicándole que es lo que está mal en su pregunta, votar en consecuencia si es lo que piensas, e incluso reportar la pregunta para su cierre. Pero en este caso, yo considero que tu propuesta de edición está correctamente rechazada

Comment: Gracias @AsieR_2, el título de la pregunta "es botón html no hace href". Porqué incluir CSS? un botón define un link URI dentro de CSS? el atributo href hace relación al CSS?

Comment: Vale @Pikoh, voy a seguir tu recomendación entonces y voy a tratar de dejar como un comentario al OP de ahora en adelante.

Comment: A veces no es fácil saber que hacer :) Te recomiendo que leas [esta página de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) que puede darte pistas sobre que ediciones son consideradas válidas y deseables. Un saludo :)

Comment: Yo en este caso pienso como @EMCode, si en el comentario de la edición se explica que se quita código que no afecta a la pregunta, no veo ningún comportamiento destructivo sino todo lo contrario, se está ayudando al op pues la pregunta sin código innecesario la va a leer más gente

Comment: @Blazerg todo es opinable por supuesto. Te recomiendo que leas el enlace que puse antes. Una de las razones de rechazar una edición es "que vaya claramente en contra de la intención del autor" que caería en este caso. Sin embargo, comentandolo con el autor, este tiene la posibilidad de aceptar una edicion a su post inmediatamente. Creo que es la forma correcta de hacerlo

Comment: Una última cosa. Precisamente porque todo es opinable, para rechazar o aprobar una edición son necesarios al menos dos votos de usuarios con la reputación suficiente. De esa manera se minimiza la posibilidad de que alguien con un criterio no muy correcto pudiera rechazar o aprobar ediciones que no fueran de acuerdo a las normas del sitio.

Comment: Sin haber participado en la revisión de la edición, concuerdo con @EMCode. El `CSS` suprimido es irrelevante para la pregunta, **pero no inconsecuente**. Un futuro usuario del sitio con conocimientos mínimos podría llegar a la conclusión de que el `CSS` afecta en algo al atributo `href`. Que sería recomendable haberlo comentado al usuario .... vale, lo compro. Pero, técnicamente hablando, lo eliminado es únicamente *ruido* sin mayor importancia. ¿ La pregunta no se entiende sin el `CSS` ? ¿ El problema no es reproducible sin él ?

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus comentarios, me sirven mucho sus puntos de vista

Comment: @Trauma Usas unas palabras que quisiera haber expresado en mi edición, es justamente esos puntos los que tomé al momento de realizar la sugerencia. Para una próxima voy a pensármelo mejor y evitar hacer ediciones que puedan entrar en conflicto con la intención del OP.

Comment: @PrettyAvocado interesante tu observación, para ser un tema subjetivo que no lleva ningún lineamiento en específico a la hora de tomar estas decisiones

Answer (score -3):

> el título de la pregunta "es botón html no hace href". Porqué incluir CSS? un botón define un link URI dentro de CSS? el atributo href hace relación al CSS?

dejo un ejemplo:

```css
.avoid-clicks {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a class=avoid-clicks href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/" target=_blank>no click</a><br/>

<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/" target=_blank>si click</a>
```

Comment: Lo siento Alo, pero no entiendo tu respuesta.

Comment: @EMCode es un caso donde el CSS bloquea el click del href desactivando los eventos del puntero, haces click y no pasa nada, pasas el mouse por arriba y no muestra el url, etc...

Comment: Creo que la respuesta de @aloMalbarez es bastante ingeniosa y demuestra que el css no puede ser suprimido olímpicamente pues puede ser un determinante del comportamiento al que hace referencia la pregunta del OP. Desafortunadamente no tiene relación con la pregunta en meta. A pesar de tener que ver con la pregunta editada que la motivó.